# Two HttpPost actions not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two Web Api POST calls in my project.But the problem is that api's working one at a time.So i need to comment one web api method to work anotherone.

### Web Api Methods

```
    //POST: api/ParamApi
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult FirstStatus(fStatus stu)
    {
         // Some codes here
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult IdReceiver(Info inf)
    {
    // some codes here
    }
```

### WebApi.Config

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: WebApiConfig.UrlPrefix + "/{controller}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/{param4}",
           defaults: new { param1 = RouteParameter.Optional, param2 = RouteParameter.Optional, param3 = RouteParameter.Optional, param4 = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiRoute",
        routeTemplate: WebApiConfig.UrlPrefix + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Which one is working and which is not? Or is it like the one that is not commented works?

Comment: you not setting an `action` value of `defaults:` object in DefaultApi route. This routes map looks strange btw, are you really need this 4 optional parameters?

Comment: and one more thing. Maybe you will try to use [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)? It is clearer then old convention based routing, as for me.

Comment: @AD8 both calls are working BUT one at a time

Answer (score 0):

no need of commenting one Http post in webApi. webApi supports any number of http post.use this route instead of using the above two config method you will write

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```